# Adding a button at the bottom of JSQMessagesCollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am newbie in iOS. Sorry for my English. Actually I want a button at the bottom of my JSQMessagesCollectionView[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7huDp.png). I have tried to put it like "drag" and "drop". But it doesn't work there. I know there must be a silly mistake which I am doing with the logic. But I need someone's help to guide me the correct way to do it. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You will have to add that button to your viewController's view and not to JSQMessagesCollectionViewenter. So after you drag and drop that button you will have to move it to your main view.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya Ok. Let me try it. And I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

`JSQMessagesCollectionViewController` was [deprecated](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/officially-deprecating-jsqmessagesviewcontroller/) I would suggest you to replace it with something else as soon as you can. [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) for example.

Comment: Thanks, but this is an Old project I'm working on. I have to continue with this as I am on a deadline to finish the project. I can't change it completely.

Comment: Also `MessageKit` is very alpha right now and won't be production ready for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

THis is out side the scope of the `JSQ` library. I guess it could be in the scope of the library depending on what the button does but `JSQ` really only helps when it comes to chat. So if the `CollectionView` you have displayed is the chat part of your app you could add a button in the `inputBar` but the screen shot does not seem to indicate that. Other wise what you are doing should be pretty strait forward. You could add a button via `StoryBoard` add `Constraints` to pin it to the bottom of your screen and hook up the outlets for it to do the action you desire. Or you could do it programmatically in your `ViewController`. That is about all the help that can be provided with the information given. If share more of you code we may be able to provide more guidance.

Comment: Yes, CollectionView I have displayed is the chat part of my app. And I wish to show the button upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is saying right this is out of the scope of the jsq library still if you want to add Button or other view i will suggest you to add it programmatically to your JSQMessagesViewController SubClass like if i am understanding your question you can add view above the JSQMessagesViewController's Subclass's inputToolBar as -

```
 UIView *v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.inputToolbar.frame.origin.y - self.inputToolbar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
 v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 [self.view addSubview:v];
```

now then you have to change the position of view / button each time keyboard appear or disappear as inputbar becomes first responder. As far as i am understanding your question i think this will help.

Although You can also change the XIB of InputToolBar and Can customize your Button in storyboard(xib) then do changes in the class of InputToolBar according to your needs.